# express middleware in nodejs обработка ошибок

Tags: node.js, express

всем привет, хочу спросить на сколько правильно использовать такой подход при обработке данных в express:

```
let errorHandler =  function (err, req, res) {
    console.log(err);
};
let dataHandler = function (data, req, res) {
    console.log(data);
};
let myMiddleware = function (data, req, res, next) {
    if (data instanceof Error) errorHandler(data, req, res);
    else dataHandler(data, req, res);
};

app.use(myMiddleware);

app.post('/login', req, res, next) {
  let user = db.getUser(req.body.login, req.body.password)
  next(user);
};
```

Ради чего это нужно? например, хочу передать обработку данных в дополнительный middleware, но next вроде как только для обработки ошибок и исключений.

Answer (score 0):

Вы сами выбираете как вам обрабатывать ошибки, поэтому **depends**, т.е. все зависит от условий где и как вам обрабатывать ошибку, какой использовать маршрут(route) и какую страницу показывать.

> При передаче какого-либо объекта в функцию next(), Express
>   интерпретирует текущий запрос как ошибку и пропустит все остальные
>   функции маршрутизации и промежуточной обработки, не являющиеся
>   функциями обработки ошибок. Для того чтобы обработать данную ошибку
>   определенным образом, необходимо создать маршрут обработки ошибок,
>   детальнее описано в [документации](https://expressjs.com/ru/guide/error-handling.html).